# How is the state property on React components implemented?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to better understand how state works in React.

I have searched the [React codebase](https://github.com/facebook/react/) and have been unable to find the implementation of the `React.Component` `state` property.

Can someone help me find the implementation of it?

Comment: Here is a starting point for the implementation of setState if you want to try to trace through it: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9def56ec0e1e71928ee999f48c00b1803ed8772a/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L57

Comment: Thanks. Is the component `state` property merely an API to `workInProgress.updateQueue.baseState`? I can't find the property definition. https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9def56ec0e1e71928ee999f48c00b1803ed8772a/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js#L177

Comment: I further traced through the code, and got down to the `ReactFiberClassComponent`, maybe that is what you're looking for: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9def56ec0e1e71928ee999f48c00b1803ed8772a/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js